# Identifying lastclick in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events

I need to get the last click arguments.

My JavaScript code:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="show(fid1,1);">Link1</a>
 <a href="#" onclick="show(fid2,2);">Link2</a>
 <a href="#" onclick="show(fid3,2);">Link3</a>
```

Now I need another JavaScript function that finds out the last click of show function's arguments. How can I do it?

```
function LastclickId(){
    //Code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to keep track of the most-recent arguments to `show()`, right? If that's indeed what you want to do, you could add two variables to your global namespace and just assign the values whenever you call `show()`:

```
last_foo = 0; // Global namespace
last_bar = 0;

function show(foo, bar) {
    last_foo = foo;
    last_bar = bar;

    ...
}
```

Then in any function on that page, you can get the values from `last_foo` and `last_bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Set a global variable in the show function. Then read it in the lastClickID function.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to have global variables around, you can wrap your related methods into a single object:

```
var yourObject = function () {

  // private members...
  var lastClicked;

  function setLastClicked(id, n) {
    lastClicked = id + "," + n
  }

  return {

      // public members...
      show: function (foo, bar) {
          // ....
          setLastClicked(foo, bar);
      },

      getLastClicked: function(){
          alert(lastClicked);
      },
};
```

}();